# Reinstall `ubuntu-desktop` after removing Gnome

Tags: unity, apt, login

I have laptop with ubuntu 14.04  I tried to install gnome to try it and after a while I wanted to remove it so I used the following command

```
apt-get remove gnom*
```

I rebooted and before the logging screen I just got a black screen

I tried to reinstall the `ubuntu-desktop` with:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

but I keep getting the following errors:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ubuntu-desktop :  
    Depends: ubuntu-session but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: unity-control-center but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: unity-settings-daemon but it is not going to be installed
    Recommends: xul-ext-webaccounts but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

searched for most of the questions with the unmet depends  but there is no change 
I tried all the following:

```
ap-get update , upgrade , remove , auto remove , clean auto , clean  , apt-get -f install, dpkg --configure -a
```

but it's the same ...

so any idea how i can fix this issue

Comment: why dont you use `xubuntu-desktop` temporarily. indeed it is good DE too. you can try just installing unity.

Comment: i tired to reinstall gnome-shell and unity but i same issue still here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed the depends packages till I reached this point

```
Depends: gnome-settings-daemon-schemas (< 3.10) but 3.12.2-0ubuntu1~trusty3 is to be installed
```

so I performed the following command that enabled me to reinstall the `ubuntu-desktop`

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-settings-daemon-schemas=3.8.6.1-0ubuntu11.2
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

I rebooted and could login to the profile